# Trying to implement a custom image format

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, bitmap, game-engine

I am trying to extend the amount of data I can store in a Bitmap per pixel.

I have created a tilemap system in Unity that references the r channel of a .PNG for the terrain type, g channel for the actor type and then combines the b and a channels to create an address that references a seperate data file where I can store an indeterminate amount of data for that tile.

My current system reads a PNG, converts it into a Color32[], then Loads chunks around the player from the Color32[]. It's all working nicely, but it is ultimately too limited for the goal.

I would like to extend the amount of data per pixel beyond the 4 parameters of the Color32. Ideally I would like to have a binary file with the width, height, name, other data, etc in a header of known length, then be able to loop over the rest of the bytes and pull say: byte terrain, byte actor, byte x2 dataAddress, byte elevation, byte ilumination, etc...

I have been doing mental gymnastics for days trying to make this work but I seem to be missing some important information when it comes to working directly with the Byte []. All my conversion attempts have caused IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: You shouldn't use bitmaps for this at all. You probably want to write your own data class and serializer.

Comment: Interesting, but rather odd.  Why this instead of a nice, simple binary stream?  Or compressed JSON or something?

Comment: Agree with the two comments before .. make your own data class / format and store all information you need in one file. This sounds like a big [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/357004)

Comment: Also seems like you're asking multiple questions, and maybe the bit about `IndexOutOfRangeException` is the important part.  What are you trying to achieve and how can we help you get there?

Comment: @Corey, I am asking multiple questions, sorry about that. I have decided to try a serialized custom class. I have created a script that reads a png and creates a color32[], converts the data in color32[] to Class MapData{ Tile[]}, and then writes the MapData class to file. My PNG is 512x512@100kb. My custom file is 4,865kb. 262144 tiles are created in MapData (512x512). Any Idea why the file is so large? and how can i post the script?  Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

From the comments it sounds like this is a fairly straight-forward serialization problem.  We can do this a couple of ways without having to worry about array manipulation unless you really want to.

I'm going to use the following classes:

```
class Map
{
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Tile[] Tiles { get; set; }
}

class Tile
{
    public byte Terrain { get; set; }
    public byte Elevation { get; set; }
    public byte Illumination { get; set; }
    public int ActorID { get; set; }
}
```

Now, using a quick fab method and some (repeatable) random numbers I've created a map that has some horribly random data in all the tiles.  With Width and Height both set to 512 we have 262,144 tiles full of random garbage.

Now we can do some serialization...

### Built In Binary Serialization

After adding some `[Serializable]` attributes to both `Map` and `Title` classes we can serialize this with the built-in .NET methods.  The `Map` class now looks like this:

```
[Serializable]
class Map
{
    // ...all the same members here...
}
```

And the code to serialize looks like this:

```
// Usings:
//  using System.Runtime.Serialization;
//  using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

var map = GenerateMap();
IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
byte[] serbytes;
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    fmt.Serialize(ms, map);
    serbytes = ms.ToArray();
}
```

Running this gives a byte array of 5.5MB size, which is not terribly great.  We can compress it, but since I have random data it doesn't pack down well - 1.5MB with Brotli compression, 2.1MB with GZip.  Actual data will probably come out nicer.  Here's the serialization section with compression:

```
// Usings:
//  using System.IO.Compression;
//  using System.Runtime.Serialization;
//  using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

var map = GenerateMap();
IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
byte[] serbytes;
using (var ms = new MemoryStream)
{
    using (var cmp = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionLevel.Optimal, true))
    {
        fmt.Serialize(ms, map);
    }
    serbytes = ms.ToArray();
}
```

Decompression and deserialization from a byte array:

```
Map deser;
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(serbytes))
using (var dec = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Decompress, true))
{
    deser = (Map)formatter.Deserialize(dec);
}
```

And that's all there is to it.

### Using ProtoBuf-net

The the built-in serializer isn't necessarily the best thing to use for general cases.  Another option is to use [`protobuf-net`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/protobuf-net/3.0.0-alpha.122) which is a bit more attribute-heavy.  You'll need to add an attribute to both classes and all members that you want to serialize, like this:

```
[ProtoContract(SkipConstructor = true)]
public class Tile
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public byte Terrain { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public byte Elevation { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public byte Illumination { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(4)]
    public byte Foo { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(5)]
    public int ActorID { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract(SkipConstructor = true)]
public class Map
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int Height { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public int Width { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(4)]
    public Tile[] Tiles { get; set; }
}
```

Now we can do the same as with the internal serializer with just a single line difference in both serializing and deserializing:

```
// Usings:
//  using ProtoBuf;

var map = GenerateMap();
byte[] serbytes;
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var cmp = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionLevel.Optimal, true))
    {
        Serializer.Serialize(ms, map);
    }
    serbytes = ms.ToArray();
}

Map deser;
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(serbyte))
using (var dec = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Decompress, true))
{
    deser = Serializer.Deserialize<Map>(ms);
}
```

Pretty simple, and with my test data it compressed down with GZip quite a bit better - 1.4MB vs 2.1MB for the native serializer.

### Or roll your own...

If you really, *really* want you can use `BinaryWriter` and `BinaryReader` to create manual `Serialize` and `Deserialize` methods on each class.  The advantage is that the file format is completely under your control.  The disadvantage is that you have to do everything yourself.

For example:

```
class Map
{
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Tile[] Tiles { get; set; }

    public void Serialize(Stream stream)
    {
        using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8, true))
        {
            writer.Write(Height);
            writer.Write(Width);
            writer.Write(Name);
            foreach (var tile in Tiles)
            {
                tile.Serialize(stream);
            }
        }
    }

    public static Map Deserialize(Stream stream)
    {
        var res = new Map();
        using (var reader = new BinaryReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8, true))
        {
            res.Height = reader.ReadInt32();
            res.Width = reader.ReadInt32();
            res.Name = reader.ReadString();
            int tileCount = res.Height * res.Width;
            res.Tiles = new Tile[tileCount];
            for (int i = 0; i < tileCount; i++)
            {
                res.Tiles[i] = Tile.Deserialize(stream);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With the test data I've been playing with the resultant GZip-compressed binary data is a little under 1.1MB, but that's high-entropy input anyway.

### In Conclusion

Binary serialization can be simple or hard, depending on what it is that you're trying to serialize.  Compression is simply a matter of adding another stage in the stream composition before you start stuffing serialized data into it.  And none of it needs you to mess with arrays if you don't want to... except for the ones in your own data.

NB: In all the examples above you can of course replace the `MemoryStream` with `FileStream` and work directly with files on disk.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent reply Corey. I ended up taking the third option, but having you lay it all out like that is very informative. Thanks again :)